# Sinon.stub.resolves returns undefined when awaited within Buffer.from

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, sinon, stub

I have the following code:

```
 describe('run()', () => {
    const ret = ['returnValue'];
    const expectedData = 'data';

    beforeEach(() => {
      sinon.stub(myStubbedService, 'myStubbedMethod').resolves(ret);
    });
    it('should not break', async () => {
      const foo = myStubbedService.myStubbedMethod();
      const bar = await myStubbedService.myStubbedMethod();
      const works = Buffer.from(bar[0], 'hex');
      console.log(works);
      const breaks = Buffer.from(await myStubbedService.myStubbedMethod()[0], 'hex');

      console.log(breaks);
    })
```

logging `works` logs the correct Buffer but logging `breaks` =>

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined
```

I am pretty sure the code for `breaks` works just the same as the code for `works` but the test fails.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your way to get the `works` is not the same as `breaks`. The way to get the `works` is easy to understand - Wait for the response of `myStubbedMethod`, then get the first item of the response.

Take a look at the way you get the `breaks`:

```
const breaks = Buffer.from(await myStubbedService.myStubbedMethod()[0], 'hex');
```

(Maybe) as you know `myStubbedService.myStubbedMethod()` return a `Promise`, when you get the `0` attribute of a Promise, you get back an undefined value.
`await` with a constant, you get the constant.

Your code will look like this:

```
const breaks = Buffer.from(await undefined, 'hex');
```

Just more parentheses:

```
const breaks = Buffer.from((await myStubbedService.myStubbedMethod())[0], 'hex');
```

Comment: makes perfect sense in the cold light of retrospection!  I think I was looking at that code for too long.  Thanks again!